# replace a term y2 in another term y4

Tags: function-construction

I want to find a term `y2` which is included in another term `y4` and replace it by a variable such as `yy4`. I tried some common function but I didn’t get a result.

```
y4 = (A1 (-Fc - fl + A1 pL) (-((A1 beta)/(A1 sp + V01)) - 
     (A2 beta \[Alpha])/(-A2 sp + V02)))/mp^2 + 1/mp A1 wp ;

y2 = (-Fc - fl + A1 pL)/mp;
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Straightforward way:

```
FullSimplify[y4, y2 == yy4]
```

> `(A1 (wp + beta yy4 (-(A1/(A1 sp + V01)) + (A2 \[Alpha])/(A2 sp - V02))))/mp`